# Keep multiple delimiters after splitting String?

Tags: javascript, node.js

The following code splits `someString` into an array, with the delimiters being specified in `separators`

```
  var separators = ['\\\.', '\\\(', '\\\)', ':', '\\\?', '\\\!', '\\\"', '\\\n'];
  var tokens = someString.split(new RegExp(separators.join('|')));

  tokens = tokens.filter(Boolean);
```

However, I would like to keep the respective delimiters when splitted. I have found several solutions, but most of them target only one delimiter which seems to be considerably easier to deal with. How would I handle multiple delimiters as in my example, and keep them when split?

Comment: Could you give an example input string and output array?

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
var someString = 'This.Is:A?:Test!With"Delimiters'
var result = someString.split(new RegExp("([" + separators.join("") + "])+"));
```

Now you have both elements and delimiters in one array:

```
console.log(result)
> ["This", ".", "Is", ":", "A", ":", "Test", "!", "With", """, "Delimiters"]
```

Splitting could be done like this:

```
var elements = [];
var delimeters = [];
for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i=i+2){
   elements.push(result[i]);
}
for(var i = 1; i < result.length; i=i+2){
   delimeters.push(result[i]);
}
```

So you get:

```
console.log(elements)
> ["This", "Is", "A", "Test", "With", "Delimeters"]
console.log(delimeters)
> [".", ":", ":", "!", """]
```

Hope it helped!